# In Excel i want to fix this code as it seems not working propaply

Tags: excel

i am trying to figure out how to use `IF AND` ,, or `IF OR`

but i need little help here

the value must be in A1:A20 ,, B1:B20

```
   =IF(A1:A20=6050 and B1:B20 =3011 ;"Value achived";"try Again")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it work like this IF(AND(log1;log2....

```
=IF(AND(A1:A20=6050;B1:B20=3011);"Value achived";"try Again")
```

---

this is an example
[image]